# JavaFX Scene builder freezes (and then crashes) when adding ContextMenu on a button

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, contextmenu, scenebuilder

I have a problem with Scene Builder. I want to add ContextMenu on a Button. When I drag and drop the ContextMenu on a Button, it works fine (it appears in the Hierarchy tab). But when I click on the pre-defined MenuItem (under the ContextMenu) in the Hierarchy tab, Scene Builder freezes and I have to shut it down.

Could someone please help me with it? I know that I can create a ContextMenu in Java code, but i wanted to do it in Scene Builder (I want to make the ContextMenu pop up when you hover over the Button, so I also somehow need to edit it's trigger - could someone please tell me how to do it?).

[there is the crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUoOu.png)

I am using Java 13 and Scene Builder 11. As you can see, the program is not responding.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

***EDIT:***
This is what i got from EventViewer. I also looked in Scene Builder and according to 'About JavaFX Scene Builder', there should be a log file called  *scenebuilder-11.0.0.log* (C:\Users\ZD\AppData\Local\Temp\scenebuilder-11.0.0.log). But there is no log file (even searching in file explorer did not find anything).

*Source*

OpenJDK Platform binary

*Summary*

The program stopped responding and was terminated.

*Description*

The problem caused that this program stopped working with Windows.
Path to the failing application:    C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\SceneBuilder.exe

***Problem signature***

*The name of the problem event:*    AppHangB1

*Application name:* SceneBuilder.exe

*Application version:*  11.0.1.0

*Application time stamp:*   5bf25cd1

*Signature of process failure:* c858

*Type of process failure:*  134217728

*Operating system version:* 10.0.18362.2.0.0.256.121

*Another process failure signature 1*:  c858a8fd12ba3c4e845361b2e92ff131

*Another process failure signature 2*:  9431

*Another process failure signature 3*:  9431e8f7e11013654814c09debfafb79

*Another process failure signature 4*:  c858

*Another process failure signature 5*:  c858a8fd12ba3c4e845361b2e92ff131

*Another process failure signature 6*:  9431

*Another process failure signature 7*:  9431e8f7e11013654814c09debfafb79

***More information about this issue***

*Set ID:*   772d0501a48434cd5a8430efceaeecf6 (1910705948434820342)

This is ***Sample.fxml***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Stop?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="611.0" prefWidth="990.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane id="k" fx:id="mainPanel" prefHeight="602.0" prefWidth="893.0" styleClass="root" stylesheets="@application.css">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButton" prefHeight="407.0" prefWidth="403.0" styleClass="MyButton" stylesheets="@application.css" text="Button" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="190.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="573.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="83.0" />
               </font>
               <textFill>
                  <LinearGradient endX="0.5095238095238095" endY="0.8428571428571429" startX="0.5285714285714286" startY="0.26666666666666666">
                     <stops>
                        <Stop color="BLACK" />
                        <Stop color="#97b83e" offset="0.27147766323024053" />
                        <Stop color="#97b83e" offset="0.5154639175257733" />
                        <Stop color="WHITE" offset="1.0" />
                     </stops>
                  </LinearGradient>
               </textFill>
            </Button>
            <ChoiceBox fx:id="choiceBox" accessibleText="lůůůůůůůůůů" layoutX="428.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="329.0" />
            <ScrollPane layoutX="428.0" layoutY="49.0" prefHeight="555.0" prefWidth="552.0">
               <content>
                  <FlowPane prefHeight="704.0" prefWidth="727.0">
                     <children>
                        <Canvas fx:id="canvas" height="705.0" onDragOver="#mouseDrag" onMouseClicked="#canvasClicked" onMouseDragged="#mouseDrag" width="727.0" />
                     </children>
                  </FlowPane>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="blackPanel" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="blackPanel" stylesheets="@application.css">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="backBtn" layoutX="356.0" layoutY="208.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#backBtnClick" prefHeight="195.0" prefWidth="278.0" styleClass="MyButton" text="Go back">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="48.0" />
               </font>
               <textFill>
                  <LinearGradient endX="1.0" endY="1.0">
                     <stops>
                        <Stop color="#1be3a9" />
                        <Stop color="#083797" offset="1.0" />
                     </stops>
                  </LinearGradient>
               </textFill>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

And this is ***Controller.java:***

```
public class Controller {

private GraphicsContext gc;
private TranslateTransition tt;

@FXML private Button button;
@FXML private Button backBtn;
@FXML private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox;
@FXML private Canvas canvas;
@FXML private AnchorPane mainPanel;
@FXML private AnchorPane blackPanel;
@FXML private ContextMenu popup;

public void initialize() {
    choiceBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Výběr1", "Výběr2", "Výběr3", "Výběr4", "Výběr5"));
    gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    double x = backBtn.getTranslateX();
    double y = backBtn.getTranslateY();

    tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(5), backBtn);
    tt.setToY(-200);
    tt.setToX(-100);

    tt.play();
    tt.setOnFinished((ae) -> {
        backBtn.setTranslateX(x);
        backBtn.setTranslateY(y);
    });

}

@FXML
private void handleButton() {
    mainPanel.setVisible(false);
    blackPanel.setVisible(true);
}

@FXML
private void backBtnClick() {
    tt.stop();
    mainPanel.setVisible(true);
    blackPanel.setVisible(false);
}


@FXML
private void canvasClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    gc.fillOval(me.getX() - 15, me.getY() -15, 30, 30);
}

@FXML
private void mouseDrag(MouseEvent mde) {
    gc.fillOval(mde.getX() - 15, mde.getY() - 15, 30, 30);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, @W4sp welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide the message log and the code in order to get more technical details?

Comment: @Juan Caicedo I just updated the question. Thanks for the welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue here, I found a *non-perfect* solution, try to remove `fx:controller` from the fxml file and open **Scene builder** as `Administrateur`.